# Create my own operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know it is possible to overload operators that already exist in c++ to define desired behavior, but is it possible to create your own operator?

Just for example, making an operator `#` that returns the size of containers:

```
template<typename T>
size_t operator#(const T& obj) { return obj.size(); }

vector<int> v(1024);
cout << #v; // prints 1024
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You need to stick with the operators the parser already knows how to handle. Overloading can extend the *meaning* of expressions, but the *syntax* is fixed.

Comment: That is a real shame, there are tons of characters that are not considered operators that could be put to good use.

Comment: @steveo225, note that there are languages where this is possible, such as Haskell.

Comment: Well, suppose you could. You would then have to define not only the code to run for your new operator, but also where it fits into precedence hierarchy. And what if two different libraries tried to define the same character as operators with different precedences? You can't know which of the two operators is meant without looking at the operand types, but you can't typecheck the operands without parsing them first, and you can't be sure how to parse the expression without first figuring out which operator it is. Down that way lies madness. Madness, I tell you!

Comment: @Henning, yep, all problems which can be solved, but C++'s parser is complex enough as is. Haskell gets away with it using namespacing and explicit precedence declarations.

Comment: @steveo225: Its a good thing you can't do that. Operator overloading of well defined operators causes enough confusion. Overloading completely new operators would make the code really hard to read. This would quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @steveo225 Yeah it's not as if C++ was already complex enough and building an arbitrary language on top if it was necessary ;) I don't think there's any chance in hell that using this wouldn't end in a maintenance nightmare. Just look at all those horrible abominations of c++ code (much more c though; the original bourne shell is infamous for that if you want to look one example up) that use macros extensively. You spend the first day just reading header files to make any sense of it.

Comment: I disagree. I think defining your own operator would be easier from a maintenance point of view. Searching the source for `operator#` seems easier than trying to track down an existing operator that has been overloaded to do something incorrect. The precedence and order of operations would be problematic though.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

Anyway hat would happen if you call your container "define" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new type (call it `Foo`) and then create a `Bar::operator Foo()` that converts a `Bar` to a `Foo`.

That probably is not what you were looking for.

You cannot make your own `#` operator. Just as a starter, where would it fit in the (already terribly bloated) C++ precedence table? Does it have left to right or right to left associativity? How are you even going to specify these things, and more?

There are so very many problems associated with creating a brand spanking new operator that the language simply does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, NO! You only can overload the all known operators and, by the way, you can't alter the behavior of the predetermined operators, then you can't change the behavior of the operator '+', by example, for the int data type. ;)