# My own operators '+' , '-'

Tags: c++, operators

1. Is it possible to create my own operators like '+' or '/'
2. Is it possible in C++?
   I have already found operator '#' , but I do not know how to do this with another.

Comment: That code sample is completely invalid. Anyway, considering 2. is whether it's possible in C++, I'm assuming 1. is in general, in which case yes, some languages let you define new operators.

Comment: Hey Kam some example code could help in working out what you're trying to accomplish. Also, have you read up on operator overloading? This might be a helpful place to start http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators if you haven't read it already

Comment: You already found `operator#`? Where? :/

Comment: @A.S.H Sooner or later someone always takes a great idea and makes a hash of it.

Comment: @A.S.H http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212375/create-my-own-operator-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can overload +, - for a given class, so they have custom behavior.
2. You can define preprocessor macros like `#define OP(a,b) ((a))-(b)*(a))` and write code like `3 OP 4`.

Other than that, I don't believe there's anything deep you can do in C++ to create your own new tokens or syntax. You can always write your own programming language - many people do - and creating a new operator pretty much means you're writing a new programming language by itself.

Comment: `OP` won't be expanded in `3 OP 4`. In order to be expanded, the token after `OP` must be `(`. However, there is the idea of named operators, one option being `3 <op> 4`.

Comment: Named operators are possible, but a horrible hack.  You have to make "op" be a global variable of a magic type.  Then you write operator <(int rhs, magictype) which returns another magic type containing the lhs argument and operator >(secondmagictype, int rhs) which actually performs the operation.

Comment: The problem is that they often have the wrong precedence.

Comment: @MartinBonner, Yes, they do often have the wrong precedence, and should typically be parenthesized if part of a larger expression. Being global isn't a huge problem if you can't change it because you made it `const` (much like how regular functions act). And yes, it does use expression templates. All expression template libraries have this magic.

Answer (score 1):

With the trivial Google search I found a table identifying 42 C++ operators that can be overloaded, and 4 C++ operators that cannot.

I did not verify this information.

Answer (score 0):

If by create, you mean to define,

You can overload many defult operators for custon types, In fact for all of:

```
+ - * / % ˆ & | ~ ! = < > += -= *= /= %= ˆ= &= |= << >> >>= <<= == != <= >= && || ++ -- , ->* -> ( ) [ ]
```

Do do custom things for your classes.

You can also define functions, like `float add(...)` and define that to do whatever you like